# Caching a website's Active Directory queries

Tags: asp.net, caching, web-applications, active-directory, directoryservices

I am often querying AD for information (ex. fetching windows principals, security groups, etc.) and would like to know of a good way to cache such information. For instance:

```
var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
var up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, User.Identity.Name);
```

What I am hoping to accomplish is for `FindByIdentity()` or something similar to decide "hey, I've recently run this query, let's not bother AD again" and fetch it from a local cache?

**Question 1:** Do the DirectoryServices or any related libraries provide such mechanics?

**Question 2:** Second, these queries are fired on Http Requests, potentially hundreds a second. If I must write my own cache mechanics, as @HillBilly.Developer suggests below, what would be the preffered scope for the cache store?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class representing the data to store, populate it, store it in the cache with an expiration.

**Untested!, but should give you the idea**

```
public class UserData 
{
     public string Username {get; set;}
     public string Email {get; set;} 
}
```

Then, where you need to populate it:

```
List<UserData> ud;

ud = (List<UserData>)Cache["UserData"];

if(ud == null) 
{
        ud = AD.RetrieveUsers();
        Cache.Add("UserData", ud, null, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.High, null);
}
```

Obviously, the call to `AD.RetrieveUsers()` would be to whatever class/function that you would have to query AD for the data.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Perhaps I should revise my question... I am hoping there is some way to let the DirectoryServices (or sibling) library cache its data... for instance `.FindByIdentity(pc, "bob")` and then next time I run this same query have it decide look for the answer in cache before querying AD again. Are there such mechanics available?

Comment: There is probably no builtin way of caching these specific AD queries. This is why you have caching available to use it in any context.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know either.  I have a feeling you'll end up writing an intermediary layer to accomplish this.